# Locking in RabbitMQ queue to prevent race conditions

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there an easy way to implement something like "locking" to prevent race conditions in RabbitMQ queue when using ack?

I have the following problem - I have a couple of clients consuming a queue using ack. Whenever a client gets a message, he acknowledges it and processes it. However if the processing fails for some reason I'd like the message to be returned to the queue.

Comment: If you are consuming in ack-mode, then when a consumer fails to ack a message, the message will be put back in the queue. That's the default behaviour of RabbitMQ. Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: Yeah, but if you have some processing to do, which may fail for some reason - say you need a second or so to process the message. If you ack the message when you first receive it, if the processing fails the message will never be successfully processed. If you ack the message when you are done processing you risk another worker to grab it and process it before you have ack-ed back and the message will be processed twice.

Comment: Yes. That's one of the reasons why consumers should be idempotent whenever possible.

Comment: If you have not acked it,rabbit will not send it to the second consumer.What can happen is that ack fails to reach and then upon channel reconnect the message is sent again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply process it and then  acknowledge it. 
And if processing fails requeue the message with `ack` or `nack`.

```
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
boolean autoAck = false;
channel.basicConsume("hello", autoAck, consumer);


QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
//do your processing    
boolean requeue = false;
channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), requeue);
```

Comment: I am afraid this won't solve the racing condition since second consumer repeats same logics over same message